# Canvas maze game smooth animation

Tags: canvas, keydown, maze

I am building a maze game based on [this](https://html5.litten.com/make-a-maze-game-on-an-html5-canvas/) tutorial. I successfully got the player rectangle to continue moving as long as you hold down the arrow keys. When you first start the game, the animation is really nice and fast, but it seems that **after playing the game for a few seconds the animation gets slower and slower**. Can anyone help me figure out why this is happening?

I have created a code snippet, but unfortunately it doesn't work correctly  because of a cross-origin error caused by the maze image I am using.

```js
var canvas;
var ctx;
var dx = 2;
var dy = 2;
var WIDTH = 482;
var HEIGHT = 482;

//movement
var x = 200,
    y = 5,
    staticX = 200,//this should be the same as x (used for resetting the game)
    staticY = 5,//this should be the same as y (used for resetting the game)
    keys = [];

var img = new Image();
var collision = 0;
var showingWinScreen = false;
var playerSize = 15;

var startTime = null,
  lastTime = null,
  endTime,  // for scale
  isRunning = false,
  FPS = 1000/60; // ideal frame rate


function rect(x,y,w,h) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(x,y,w,h);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
}

function clear() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
}

function drawMaze() {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}

function drawPlayer() {
  doKeyDown();

  ctx.fillStyle = "purple";
  rect(x, y, 15,15);
}

function draw() {
  clear();

  if(showingWinScreen) {
    isRunning = false;
    drawRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height,"black");
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.font = "20px Arial";
    ctx.fillText("You Won! Click to play again", 70,canvas.height/2);
    ctx.fillText("Time Elapsed: " + endTime, 70, canvas.height*0.6);
    return;
  }
  isRunning = true;

  drawMaze();
  drawPlayer();
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

function drawRect(leftX, topY, width, height, drawColor) {
  ctx.fillStyle = drawColor;
  ctx.fillRect(leftX,topY,width, height);
}

//timer
function loop(timeStamp) {

  if (!startTime) {
    startTime = timeStamp;
  }

  var timeDiff = lastTime ? timeStamp - lastTime : FPS,
      timeElapsed = timeStamp - startTime,
      timeScale = timeDiff / FPS; // adjust variations in frame rates

  lastTime = timeStamp;

  var totalTime = timeElapsed*0.001;
  var minutes = Math.floor(totalTime / 60);
  var seconds = totalTime % 60;

  drawRect(WIDTH,10,70, 30,"black");
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.font = "14px Arial";
  ctx.fillText(minutes + ":" + (seconds).toFixed(2), WIDTH*1.04, 30);

  endTime = minutes + ":" + (seconds).toFixed(0);

  if (isRunning) requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

function init() {

  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  img.src = "https://html5.litten.com/images/maze.gif";
  var framesPerSecond = 60;
  return setInterval( function() {
    draw();
  }, 1000/framesPerSecond);
}

function checkcollision() {
  var imgd = ctx.getImageData(x, y, playerSize, playerSize);
  var pix = imgd.data;
  for (var i = 0; n = pix.length, i < n; i += 4) {
    if (pix[i] == 0) {
      collision = 1;
    }
  }
}

function checkWin() {
  var imageData = ctx.getImageData(x, y, playerSize, playerSize);
  var r, g, b, a;
  for (var i = 0; i+3 < imageData.data.length; i += 4) {
    r = imageData.data[i];
    g = imageData.data[i+1];
    b = imageData.data[i+2];
    a = imageData.data[i+3];

    //if red
    if ( r === 255 && b === 0 ) {
      console.log(' R: ' + r + '<br>G: ' + g + '<br>B: ' + b);
      isRunning = false;
      showingWinScreen = true;
    }
  }
}



function handleMouseClick(event) {
  if (showingWinScreen) {
    showingWinScreen = false;
    x = staticX;
    y = staticY;
    draw();
  }
}

//arrow keys
function doKeyDown(){
  //left
  if (keys[37]) {
    if (x - dx > 0){
      x -= dx;
      checkcollision();
      checkWin();
      if (collision == 1){
        x += dx;
        collision = 0;
      }
    }
  }
  //right
  if (keys[39]) {
    if (x + dx < WIDTH){
      x += dx;
      checkcollision();
      checkWin();
      if (collision == 1){
        x -= dx;
        collision = 0;
      }
    }
  }
  //down
  if (keys[40]) {
    if (y + dy < HEIGHT ){
      y += dy;
      checkcollision();
      checkWin();
      if (collision == 1){
        y -= dy;
        collision = 0;
      }
    }
  }
  //up
  if (keys[38]) {
    if (y - dy > 0){
      y -= dy;
      checkcollision();
      checkWin();
      if (collision == 1){
        y += dy;
        collision = 0;
      }
    }
  }
}

init();

window.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
  keys[e.keyCode] = true;
});
window.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
  keys[e.keyCode] = false;
});

canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", handleMouseClick);

(function () {
  var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
  window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;
})()
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="582" height="582">
      This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
      </canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest problem here?
Your timer.

Let's remove everything related to the canvas and just try to log how many times **per frame** you are drawing this little time counter:

```js
// If everything was ok, frame_count should never be higher than 1
var frame_count = 0;
var total_count = 0;

function frame_loop() {
  frame_log.textContent = frame_count;
  total_log.textContent = total_count;
  // reset our frame counter
  frame_count = 0;
  // do it again next loop
  requestAnimationFrame(frame_loop);
}
frame_loop();

var startTime = null,
  lastTime = null,
  endTime,  // for scale
  isRunning = false,
  FPS = 1000/60; // ideal frame rate

function draw() {
  isRunning = true;
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

//timer
function loop(timeStamp) {

  frame_count ++;
  total_count ++;
  
  if (!startTime) {
    startTime = timeStamp;
  }

  var timeDiff = lastTime ? timeStamp - lastTime : FPS,
      timeElapsed = timeStamp - startTime,
      timeScale = timeDiff / FPS; // adjust variations in frame rates

  lastTime = timeStamp;

  var totalTime = timeElapsed*0.001;
  var minutes = Math.floor(totalTime / 60);
  var seconds = totalTime % 60;
  endTime = minutes + ":" + (seconds).toFixed(0);
  if (isRunning) requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

function init() {
  var framesPerSecond = 60;
  return setInterval( function() {
    draw();
  }, 1000/framesPerSecond);
}


init();
```

```html
<p>number of times loop() has been called <b>during last frame</b>: <span id="frame_log"></span></p>

<p>number of times loop() has been called <b>in total</b>: <span id="total_log"></span></p>
```

You see the problem?
In a few seconds, you draw this text a thousands times **per frame**.
This needs to be drawn only once per frame.

That's because you did mix `setInterval` and `requestAnimationFrame`.

As a rule of thumb, never do this.
`requestAnimationFrame` should be called only from its callback, or from an initializing function.

`setInterval` should not be used to call anything that should be painted at high frequency. That's requestAnimationFrame's job.

So get rid of this `setInterval`, and use a single `requestAnimationFrame` loop:

```js
// If everything was ok, frame_count should never be higher than 1
var frame_count = 0;
var total_count = 0;

function frame_loop() {
  frame_log.textContent = frame_count;
  total_log.textContent = total_count;
  // reset our frame counter
  frame_count = 0;
  // do it again next loop
  requestAnimationFrame(frame_loop);
}
frame_loop();

var startTime = null,
  lastTime = null,
  endTime,  // for scale
  isRunning = false,
  FPS = 1000/60; // ideal frame rate

function draw() {
  isRunning = true;
  // remove this one, loop will call itself
//  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

//timer
function loop(timeStamp) {

  frame_count ++;
  total_count ++;
  
  if (!startTime) {
    startTime = timeStamp;
  }

  var timeDiff = lastTime ? timeStamp - lastTime : FPS,
      timeElapsed = timeStamp - startTime,
      timeScale = timeDiff / FPS; // adjust variations in frame rates

  lastTime = timeStamp;

  var totalTime = timeElapsed*0.001;
  var minutes = Math.floor(totalTime / 60);
  var seconds = totalTime % 60;
  endTime = minutes + ":" + (seconds).toFixed(0);

  if (isRunning) requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

function init() {
  isRunning  = true;
  // from init only we can start the loop
  loop();
}


init();
```

```html
<p>number of times loop() has been called <b>during last frame</b>: <span id="frame_log"></span></p>

<p>number of times loop() has been called <b>in total</b>: <span id="total_log"></span></p>
```

Now we've fixed that huge problem, we can check a bit more the rest of what you are doing...

Do not mix the game logic with the rendering one.

The basic setup is one main loop, which will call all the sub-functions, and itself.
These sub-functions are basically

- 1 update the scene
- 2 render the scene

Inside the update part, you'll update the player position, check for collisions etc.

The rendering will then just have to use the updated values.

```js
(function(imgurl) {

  function mainLoop(t) {
    update(t);
    render();
    if (isRunning) {
      requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
    }
  }

  function update(t) {
    updateTimer(t);
    updatePlayer(t);
  }

  function render() {
    clear();

    if (showingWinScreen) {
      showWinScreen();
      return;
    }

    renderTimer();
    renderMaze();
    renderPlayer();
  }

  function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    img.onload = mainLoop;
    img.src = imgurl;

    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", handleMouseClick);

    isRunning = true;
  }

  function showWinScreen() {
    isRunning = false;
    drawRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, "black");
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.font = "20px Arial";
    ctx.fillText("You Won! Click to play again", 70, canvas.height / 2);
    ctx.fillText("Time Elapsed: " + endTime, 70, canvas.height * 0.6);
  }

  var canvas;
  var ctx;
  var dx = 2;
  var dy = 2;
  var WIDTH = 482;
  var HEIGHT = 482;

  //movement
  var x = 200,
    y = 5,
    staticX = 200,
    staticY = 5,
    keys = [];

  var img = new Image();
  var collision = 0;
  var showingWinScreen = false;
  var playerSize = 15;


  //timer
  var startTime = null,
    lastTime = null,
    endTime, // for scale
    isRunning = false,
    timer = '';

  function updateTimer(timeStamp) {

    if (!startTime) {
      startTime = timeStamp;
    }

    var timeElapsed = timeStamp - startTime;

    lastTime = timeStamp;

    var totalTime = timeElapsed * 0.001;
    var minutes = Math.floor(totalTime / 60);
    var seconds = totalTime % 60;

    timer = minutes + ":" + (seconds).toFixed(2);
    endTime = minutes + ":" + (seconds).toFixed(0);

  }

  function renderTimer() {
    drawRect(WIDTH, 10, 70, 30, "black");
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.font = "14px Arial";
    ctx.fillText(timer, WIDTH * 1.04, 30);
  }

  // merge both collision and win in a single check
  function checkPosition() {
    collision = 0;
    showingWinScreen = false;
    var imgd = ctx.getImageData(x, y, playerSize, playerSize);
    var pix = imgd.data;
    var r, g, b, a;
    for (var i = 0, n = pix.length; i < n; i += 4) {
      r = pix[i];
      g = pix[i + 1];
      b = pix[i + 2];
      a = pix[i + 3];
      if (r == 0) {
        collision = 1;
      }
      //if red
      if (r === 255 && b === 0) {
        console.log(' R: ' + r + '<br>G: ' + g + '<br>B: ' + b);
        isRunning = false;
        showingWinScreen = true;
      }
    }
  }

  function updatePlayer() {

    var direction_x = 0;
    var direction_y = 0;

    // get the directions
    if (keys[37]) { //left
      direction_x = -dx;
    }
    if (keys[39]) { //right
      direction_x += dx;
    }
    if (keys[40]) { //bottom
      direction_y += dy;
    }
    if (keys[38]) { //top
      direction_y -= dy;
    }

    var updated = false;

    // update the position
    if (x + direction_x > 0 && x + direction_x < WIDTH) {
      x += direction_x;
      updated = true;
    }
    if (y + direction_y > 0 && y + direction_y < HEIGHT) {
      y += direction_y;
      updated = true;
    }

    // check for collision/win
    if (updated) {
      checkPosition();
    }

    // undo if needed
    if (collision === 1) {
      x -= direction_x;
      y -= direction_y;
    }
  }

  function renderPlayer() {
    drawRect(x, y, playerSize, playerSize, "purple");
  }

  function renderMaze() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  }

  function clear() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  }

  function drawRect(leftX, topY, width, height, drawColor) {
    ctx.fillStyle = drawColor;
    ctx.fillRect(leftX, topY, width, height);
  }

  function handleMouseClick(event) {
    if (showingWinScreen) {
      showingWinScreen = false;
      x = staticX;
      y = staticY;
      mainLoop(); // restart
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
  });
  window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    keys[e.keyCode] = false;
  });

  init();

})('data:image/gif;base64,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');
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="582" height="582"></canvas>
```

There are still many things to improve there, for instance, you'd probably be better have your maze in a JSON format and look only at your `x` and `y`  values for collision and win rather than checking the pixel drawn, but that'd be a bit too much for this little answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your awesome answer Kaiido! That makes a lot of sense.
If you have time for one more question, it seems like there is a problem with the timer in the answer code you posted. Is it OK to use requestAnimationFrame here? That was the only way I could figure out to fix it.

    `function update(t) {
      updatePlayer(t);
      requestAnimationFrame(updateTimer);
    }`